# R: Merging two data frames where DF1 rownames = values in a column in DF2, AND where DF1 colnames = values from MULTIPLE columns in DF2

Tags: r

I have an empty sample dataframe DF1 like this:

```
DF1 <- matrix(data = NA, nrow = 4, ncol = 4)
rownames(DF1) <- c("Q1_2020", "Q2_2020", "Q3_2020", "Q4_2020")
colnames(DF1) <- seq(1,4,1)
DF1
         1  2  3  4
Q1_2020 NA NA NA NA
Q2_2020 NA NA NA NA
Q3_2020 NA NA NA NA
Q4_2020 NA NA NA NA
```

The colnames in DF1 represent a "lag" value which will also be included in DF2.

I have another sample dataframe DF2 like this:

```
Loss <- c(100,200,150,100,50,0,0,50,500,0)
AccidentQtr <- c("Q1_2020", "Q1_2020", "Q1_2020", "Q2_2020", "Q2_2020", "Q2_2020", "Q3_2020", "Q3_2020", "Q4_2020", "Q4_2020")
Q1_2020 <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,4,4)
Q2_2020 <- c(2,2,2,3,3,3,4,4,NA,NA)
Q3_2020 <- c(3,3,3,4,4,4,NA,NA,NA,NA)
Q4_2020 <- c(4,4,4,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA)
DF2 <- data.frame(Loss, AccidentQtr, Q1_2020, Q2_2020, Q3_2020, Q4_2020)
DF2

   Loss AccidentQtr Q1_2020 Q2_2020 Q3_2020 Q4_2020
1   100     Q1_2020       1       2       3       4
2   200     Q1_2020       1       2       3       4
3   150     Q1_2020       1       2       3       4
4   100     Q2_2020       2       3       4      NA
5    50     Q2_2020       2       3       4      NA
6     0     Q2_2020       2       3       4      NA
7     0     Q3_2020       3       4      NA      NA
8    50     Q3_2020       3       4      NA      NA
9   500     Q4_2020       4      NA      NA      NA
10    0     Q4_2020       4      NA      NA      NA
```

The values in columns 3:6 are those same "lag" values from DF1 that I would like to join on.

I want to aggregate the data from the "Loss" column in DF2 into the format of DF1 where the value in the AccidentQtr column = the row name in DF1, and  but am struggling with how I would do this or how I would even merge/join the data.

Comment: What output you want?

Comment: Hi, I didn't fully understand your goal . .. you have 10 values in the Loss column in DF2 and want to _aggregate_ it into a matrix with 16 entries? 
Maybe it's a good start to reformat DF2 like `melt(DF2, id.=c("Loss","AccidentQtr"))`